# Can I use AngularJS's $q outside an Angular component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angular-promise

I am writing a browser app, and I have a file that creates an object and initializes it. The app is written in AngularJS, but the file in question is plain Javascript, outside the Angular ecosystem.

I want to use promises in that file, but since Angular contains an [an implementation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) of [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), I'd rather just use that than bring in another library.

I am also using RequireJS.

So, is there a way to use $q in a non-Angular file?

Comment: i don't see why not- just pass it at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by using the [**angular.injector()**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector) method which returns an [**$injector**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) function that can be injected with dependencies that you need (e.g. `$http`, `$q`) through its `invoke()` method.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ajRd6Vgbwajldpn0bHfm?p=preview)**

Something like this:

```
angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(['$q', function($q) {

  $q.when('hello world').then(function(message) {
    window.alert(message);
  });

}]);
```

Note that the array passed to `angular.injector()` is a list of modules, I included the `ng` module because that is where the AngularJS core dependencies are located.

Comment: But this way, ``$q`` will use a different ``$rootScope`` as the rest of the app. So using ``$rootScope.$apply()`` on the "normal" ``$rootScope`` (e.g. in unit tests) won't work for that ``$q``, right?

Comment: @Ignitor. That is not necessarily true, the `ng` module is technically added as a dependency for all modules. Therefore the `$rootScope` for the module that you create also shares the `$rootScope` of the `ng` module. As of the writing of this comment, the angular.js version is 1.5.8, you will see that the `ng` module is added as a default module for all modules in the bootstrap process, [**in this line**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.8/src/Angular.js#L1688). Additionally, the native angularjs services, providers, factories and values resides in this module.

Comment: Just tried it: I saved a reference to the ``$rootScope`` within a controller and compared it to the ``$rootScope`` I've got from this: ``angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
console.dir($rootScope);
}])``. They do *not* match and even have different ``$id``s.